# Strange issue with several simultaneous connections to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, linux-kernel, centos

I have a cron that runs a bash file and this bash file will open about 1000 PHP scripts simultaneously, each one of these PHP scripts makes a connection with MySQL. After some time running it, I see intermittent MySQL errors like:

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (4)`

I figured out that error (4) is OS level (interrupted system call).

at `/var/log/messages/` has a lot of `kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet` messages, I don't know if it is related to this issue.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Why do you need to run 1000 php scripts in parallel?

Comment: well it is a big system that need to run at parallel.

Comment: Why can't you run 100 in parallel, each doing 10 tasks? Or why don't you stagger them so that the first 100 run, and when each terminates another starts until all 1000 have run, queueing them? There are generally alternative ways to architect something to avoid 1000 concurrent tasks

Comment: You should show at least the SQL statement(s) and at least one example script in your scripts here, that someone can help you.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43205/nf-conntrack-table-full-dropping-packet#43220

Comment: That doesn't sound like a reason at all, but if that really is the case, throw more resources at it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short your server is busy, you have reach the maximum allowed connections.

To fix this increase maximum configured connections limit

```
# Temporarily Solution
echo 524288 > /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max


# Permanent Solution
# Add following line on /etc/rc.d/rc.local

$ vim /etc/rc.d/rc.local
echo 524288 > /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max
```

### $ chmod a+x /etc/rc.d/rc.local

edited

simpler way to do this is 
/etc/sysctl.conf file. 
Open a ssh/term with root privileges and add a line to 
/etc/sysctl.conf file as:
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 65536
and save the file, then enter:
sysctl -p

Comment: Cool thank u, i didn't tested yet but it sound good, but i have a question this error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (4) could be cuz my system is busy? or this would fix only kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet?

Comment: i can't restart the server also if i do echo 524288 > /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max would'nt need to restart right?

Comment: Look: 
cat /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_count
65512
cat /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max
65536

Comment: Yeah because your server reached to the maximum allowed connections therefor it can't open a new one and reduce this error. try to run 100  files instead of 1000 and see if the same error occurs if not  increase the connections limit to fix it. Regards.

Comment: this wouldn't need restart "echo 524288 > /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max"?

Comment: i did it but im a bit afraid about run sysctl -p and the server restart or stop, it could happens or not?